# Can't get reference to the existing instance of Word object from excel; runtime error 429

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a script in excel which opens a certain MS Word file. Both Word and Excel object libraries are included. Here is the code of initializing an instance of Word:

```
Sub InitializeWord()

    'Path for the upper-level folder
    Dim RootPath As String
    'Path for the destination of my document
    Dim WordDocPath As String

    RootPath = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\"))
    WordDocPath = RootPath & "Templates\" & "ÎÌÄ.docm"

    'Try to get a reference to existing Word instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, Word.Application)

    'If WordApp still references nothing - create a new instance of WordApp and open the document.
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'word will be closed while running
        WordApp.Visible = True
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(WordDocPath)

    'Else search open documents for the file you need and reference it, if there's none - open it.
    Else
        Dim OpenedDoc As Object
        For Each OpenedDoc In Word.Documents
            If StrComp(OpenedDoc.FullName, WordDocPath, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                Set WordDoc = OpenedDoc
                Exit For
            End If
        Next OpenedDoc
        If WordDoc Is Nothing Then
            Set WordDoc = Word.Documents.Open(WordDocPath)
        End If
    End If
    Set Headers = WordDoc.SelectContentControlsByTitle("DocHeader")(1)
    WordApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

The script correctly creates the instance of word when there is none, but when there is word app already opened during the runtime, the script fails to get the `Word.Application` Object and tries to open the document the second time. Disabling `On Error Resume Next` string gets Runtime Error "ActiveX component can't create object".

Comment: You need to use `On Error` properly. As is, it will just ignore all errors. I think braX already nailed it but consider improving your error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetObject()` expects a string value, not a reference, so add quotes to it:

```
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```